# Falha ao aplicar a mascara currency em um if inline

Tags: html, angularjs

Tenho uma condição onde preciso aplicar a mascara monetária.

```
<td>
    <div class="pull-left">{{nota.issRetido[0] === true ? nota.qtdNotasEmitidas | currency : '-'}}</div>
    <div class="pull-right">{{nota.issRetido[0] === false ? nota.qtdNotasEmitidas| currency  : '-'}}</div>
</td>
```

Ao passar o '*| currency :*' para condição quando for *true*, retorna *siyntax
Syntax Error*

Porém, esse erro só ocorre na condição desse if inline. Como faço para colocar a mascara nessa situação?

Comment: Se não coloquei, é pq me retorna um erro. E n tem porque colocar um código que sei onde está o erro. E o currency, como tá descrição, estava tentando aplica-lo dentro do: {{nota.issRetido[0] === false ? nota.qtdNotasEmitidas | currency  : '-'}}

Comment: Então, mas para podermos ajudar, precisamos testar o código, saber o que tem em `nota.qtdNotasEmitidas` .. etc etc. Se não quer adicionar o código, crie um [mcve]. Verifique a versão que esta usando do *AngularJS*.

Comment: Tente fazer com `if else` normal aplicando o currency

Comment: Como seria, esse *if else* normal?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, no código você está adicionando a máscara ao currency porém não inserindo a condição `else`, então para tirar quaisquer dúvidas vai um exemplo usando parênteses `()` para limitar a condição:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.nota = {};
  $scope.nota.issRetido = [];
  $scope.nota.issRetido[0] = true;
  $scope.nota.qtdNotasEmitidas = 1;
  });
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h3>Limitando com parênteses e adicionando máscara "currency : '-'"</h3>
<div class="pull-left">{{nota.issRetido[0] === true ? (nota.qtdNotasEmitidas | currency : '-') : '' }}</div>
<div class="pull-right">{{nota.issRetido[0] === false ? (nota.qtdNotasEmitidas | currency:'-') : '' }}</div>

<h3>limitando com parênteses e sem máscara</h3>
<div class="pull-left">{{nota.issRetido[0] === true ? (nota.qtdNotasEmitidas | currency) : '-' }}</div>
<div class="pull-right">{{nota.issRetido[0] === false ? (nota.qtdNotasEmitidas | currency) : '-' }}</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```